# limit allowed values for polynomial with RANSACRegressor

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, loss, ransac

I have the following white pixels as input data and use sklearn.linear_model.RANSACRegressor to fit a polynomial of degree 2 (quadratic) to avoid outliers. The result in this case is shown in red and is completely correct:

[image]

However, I know in my application that the quadratic curve will always have its minimum/maximum on the right side of this image (but I don't know at which height) and that the curvature can't be that strong.
To put it differently: I already know that my best fit should be like the blue line and that the other points are corrupt outliers.

Is there a way to control or limit the outcome of RANSACRegressor by (e.g.) providing a loss function which punishes very strong curvatures but still tries to find the best fit when using lower curvatures?

Thanks in advance for any hints or links :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I found an easy (but most likely: costly) way of doing it:

```
def is_model_valid(estimator, X, y):
    return abs(estimator.coef_[2]) < 0.001
```

and use this function as an input parameter to [RANSACRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.RANSACRegressor.html) to disallow models with high curvature..

Or alternatively to only allow min/max to be on the right side of the picture

(assuming the picture is 700 pixels):

```
def is_model_valid2(estimator, X, y):
    return ((-1.0 * estimator.coef_[1]) / (2.0*estimator.coef_[2])) > 600
```